# Battery life on Zenbook UX51 Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.04, battery

My battery life is 2h30m in my Ubuntu 12.10 but in Windows I had 7h00
I installed jupiter, nothing changed. What can I do?

Comment: What is your GPU? Does it have optimus technology?

Answer (score -1):

Use powertop to check what is draining the battery. Install bumblebee and make sure that the GPU is off (/proc/acpi/bbswitch).

Comment: How can the user install that software?